How to run pipenv install?
I am trying to run pipenv install in cmd. But i keep getting the error
Warning: Python 3.9 was not found on your system...

Neither 'pyenv' nor 'asdf' could be found to install Python.


You can specify specific versions of Python with:

$ pipenv --python path\to\python`

I have python install and i ran pip install pipenv and it says

`Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in c:\users\lilys\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (2024.0.1)

Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\lilys\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from pipenv) (2024.7.4)

Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=67 in c:\users\lilys\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from pipenv) (70.2.0)

Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv>=20.24.2 in c:\users\lilys\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from pipenv) (20.26.3)

Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.7 in c:\users\lilys\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from virtualenv>=20.24.2->pipenv) (0.3.8)

Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.12.2 in c:\users\lilys\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from virtualenv>=20.24.2->pipenv) (3.15.4)

Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<5,>=3.9.1 in c:\users\lilys\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from virtualenv>=20.24.2->pipenv) (4.2.2)`

I also ran `pipenv sync --python=/path/to/location/python` and got

`Usage: pipenv sync [OPTIONS]

Try 'pipenv sync -h' for help.

Error: Invalid value for '--python': Expected Python at path /path/to/location/python does not exist

How do i fix this?`

Try to run the following
python -m pip show pipenv # see if python is installed properly
pipenv --py # see the python that env is using
python --version # make sure the python you are using is version 3.9


I ran 'pipenv --py' and it says 'No virtualenv has been created for this project C:\Users\lilys\Downloads\resy-reservations-bot-main  yet!
Aborted!' And i ran 'python --version' and got 'Python 3.12.4'. Should i uninstall this version and install version 3.9?

yes, u did not configure the environment properly, switch to python 3.9 would be ok

If you use pipenv install, then it means you have Pipfile already.
The message says that you don't have python version 3.9. One way to fix is changing python version in pipfile to version that you have.

pipenv will automatically install a missing Python version when you run the pipenv install command.
For this to work, you must install the pyenv or asdf Python packages on your computer before running the command.
